# burning permit (meaning)

Tags: meaning

An excerpt from a brochure about basic electrical safety for industrial electricians:

> Use only electric equipment and tools that are approved for the atmosphere
>   found inside the confined area. It may be necessary to obtain **a
>   burning permit** to operate tools that have open brushes and that spark
>   when they are operated.

What exactly is a burning permit?

Comment: In general, a "*verb*ing permit" is a permit (or license) to perform the specified action. A "building permit" is permission to build, for example. I haven't heard of burning permits in this exact context, but presumably it is a permit to have an open flame, such as a torch or heater. The sparks from a drill's motor are not open flames, but the dangers presented may be similar (they could ignite a flammable gas), so perhaps the same kind of permit is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ordinarily a *burn permit* or *burning permit* is formal document issued by a municipal authority or fire department allowing the recipient to burn yard waste such as leaves, grass cuttings and branches.

In the case at hand the term appears to be a mistake for ***hot work permit***, a formal document which must be secured from the environmental safety authority with jurisdiction over the worksite whenever work involves a possible fire hazard.

> **Hot work** is any process that can be a source of ignition when flammable material is present or can be a fire hazard regardless of the presence of flammable material in the workplace. Common hot work processes are welding, soldering, cutting and brazing. When flammable materials are present, industrial processes such as grinding and drilling become hot work processes.
>
> In some countries, such as the UK and Canada, a hot work permit is required for hot work.
> —[Wikipedia, Hot Work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_work)